# how to Autowire a property before another?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Using spring boot, how to Autowire the applicationContext ?

It must be autowired before the call of `endpoint()`

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com.dev.core.services", "com.dev.core.wservices"})
@ImportResource({ "classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" })
public class ContextConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Autowired
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ContextConfig.class);
    }   
    @Bean 
    public EndpointImpl endpoint() { 
    //  applicationContext is null how to fix that ?
        EndpointImpl endpoint = 
           new EndpointImpl(cxfBus, applicationContext.getBean(IWCustomerService.class) ); 
        endpoint.publish("/CustomerService"); 
        return endpoint; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` fields are ignored by Spring.

Unless you're in some kind of `main` method, setting up your application, you should never have to use the `ApplicationContext` directly.

Here, you want to use it to extract a bean of type `IWCustomerService`. Instead, let Spring inject it for you.

```
@Bean 
public EndpointImpl endpoint(IWCustomerService customerService) { 
    EndpointImpl endpoint = 
       new EndpointImpl(cxfBus, customerService); 
    endpoint.publish("/CustomerService"); 
    return endpoint; 
}
```